# Kotlin equivalent of parallelStream in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Kotlin, I can call:

```
val newList = someList.parallelStream().map { doSomethingAndReturnObject() }.toList()
```

and it will return me a list.

But since parallelStream is not recommended when handling IO actions (such like HTTP requests), I'll need to use Coroutines.
What would be the equivalent of the parallelStream code example above in Coroutines?